# PivotTable - Filter Row

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013, vba

I am working on creating a pivot table for the data I have. The data looks something like below:

```
    ID  Policy_July Policy_June Policy_May  Policy_April            Label

    13  High        Med         High        High        High        Good
    2   Low         Low         Low         Low         Low         Good
    3   Low         Low         Low         Low         Low         Good
    4   High        Med         High        High        High        Good
    5   High        Low         High        High        High        Good
    6   Low         Low         Low         Low         Low         Bad
    7   High        Med         High        High        High        Bad
    8   High        Low         High        High        High        Bad
```

I am comparing results from July with other months. Is there a way I can add a filter for row to enable me to change "Policy_June" to "Policy_March"? Basically, instead of having a filter for column, can I have filter for row in pivot table? If so, can you please guide me on how can I do it?

Again, what I am looking for is to have a filter button above the pivot table that would enable me to change "Policy_June" to "Policy_April".

Secondly, is there a way I can have "Grand Total" as a column (like I have at the bottom of pivot table)? I am trying to sum the value of "Bad" and "Good" for "High" and show the result in the column in yellow.

Let me know if you need any additional clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can normalize your data by giving it a layout similar to this:

```
ID   PolicyMonth  Status  Label
13   July         High    Good
13   June         Med     Good
13   May          High    Good
...
```

and create a Pivot with ID in vertical (Row Labels) and Status in horizontal (Column Labels) direction. You then can filter Row and Column Labels for a single (or multiple) values.

Not sure though how you would like to process the crosspoint data (Status, Label) as you only can sum/count/average/min/max by default ... this possibly may require conversion of Low/Med/High into numbers (0,1,2) and an average for the row total.

**Edit**

Further to your comments I understand you want to analyze a Delta ...

[image: open image in new tab to get larger size]

- columns A..G contain original data
- columns H..L contain a numeric representation according to formula

  H5: `=IF(B5="High",2,IF(B5="Med",1,0))`
- cells C1 and C2 contain the month names to be compared ... they are identical to headers in H4..L4; change as you like ... data validation using a list of values and in-cell drop-down is thinkable
- column M - big trick - is calculated using INDEX and MATCH functions, i.e.

  M4: `=INDEX(H5:L5,1,MATCH($C$1,$H$4:$L$4,0))-INDEX(H5:L5,1,MATCH($C$2,$H$4:$L$4,0))`
- Pivot table is created with Diff as Row Label and count(ID) as data, displaying the ones that stayed flat (0), jumped up or down by 1 or 2 levels ... this of course can be filtered to supress or highlight the ones staying equal.
- Result in Diff could be further processed into a DiffText using nested IF's and displayed in pivot rows instead of Diff
- in screenshot: 3 ID's stayed unchanged, 3 ID's improved by 1 level, 2 ID's improved by 2 levels
- Pivot table can drill down to the ID level to show WHO were the good/bad guys if you add ID to the row labels

Hope this comes closer than my 1st attempt.

*open image in new tab to get larger size*

Comment: Mike thanks for your reply. Since, I am trying to compare policy from July to June, I don't think your approach would work. So basically, I want to see July value as a Column and June value as a Row label.

Comment: and what do you want to display at the intersection between any 2 months?

Comment: At the intersection, I would like to show how many people remained in the same policy. So for ex: let's say there are 25 people in July and their distribution for policy looks something like this: # of High = 15 # of Low = 10. Now back in June, those 25 people had a different policy. # of High = 20 # of Low = 5. So at the interection, I would like to show people whose policy didn't change.  for ex: 14 people. The policy for the remaining people either went from High to Low or Low to High. Hope this makes sense. I appreciate your help.

Comment: and ID in your original post stands for the individuum ... meaning that Person 13 in June was MED and changed to HIGH in July ... ?

Comment: Thanks Mike. The results that I am looking for is something different. So referring back to you screen shot and referring to cell A..F. If you place "July" under Row Label and "June" under Column label and do a count of ID under Values. That's what I have right now. Pretty simple right?  But what I trying to do, is have a filter for that Column Label, so I have the option of selecting either March, April or any other Month to compare the numbers moving up and down.  Let me know if you need additional info. I am not able to paste a screen shot of what I have since I don't have reputation.